# how can I prevent CreateReactApp compilation from stopping on lint errors?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, create-react-app, tslint

How can I allow createReactApp to compile despite warnings from TSLint or ESLint ?

For example, compilation will stop on `[tslint] block is empty (no-empty)` which is very annoying.

I want the warning to show but not to block compilation.

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: That kind of ruins the whole point of using create react app.

Comment: I've made it somehow, but I totally forgot how. I'll check my code and reply you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to adjust your `tslint.json` file to show `tslint` problems as warnings instead of errors, which should allow your code to compile.

https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript/issues/238#issuecomment-360142264

> Indeed - the plugin we're using for tslint refers to the severity defined configuration file (i.e. tslint.json). If there is no severity defined, everything will fire up on error level.
>
> It should be possible to use the warning level by adding "defaultSeverity": "warning" to the tslint.json in the generated project's root directory. Can you give this a try?